# Assignment to a function pointer in the global scope

Tags: c++, syntax-error, function-pointers, global-scope

I am trying to define a type for function pointers, in c++. However, once I define the pointer `funcp` as a `fptr`, I cannot redefine the pointer as a different function, `times`. This program does not even compile. Is this because I have to delete the `nullptr` before reassigning `times` to `funcp`?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int (*fptr)(int, int);

int times(int x, int y)
{
    return x*y;
}

fptr funcp = nullptr;

funcp = times;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you move the assignment funcp = times; inside main then it will work. your problem is a scoping issue.

Comment: Why are you setting `funcp` to `nullptr` then reassigning it? A simple `fptr funcp = times;` would suffice in this instance.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I initially tried `fptr funcp = times;`, but then I was wondering what would happen if I had to change the value `funcp` points to.

Comment: If you need to change it then the assignment would be within a function body. You can't do assignments at the global level (i.e., outside of a function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to do that outside of any function. Try that:

```
int main()
{
    funcp = times;
    return 0;
}
```

Your question has nothing special for C++17. To make it a little more modern and easier to read you may use the `using` instead of `typedef`:

```
using fptr = int (*)(int, int);
```

Comment: Another way, to avoid repetition, is `using fptr = decltype(times) *;` (although personally I would use a non-pointer typedef)